# Image and bitmap with easeljs don't display

Tags: javascript, image, bitmap, easeljs

I've read a bunch of topics here about this but I can't figure out what my problem is.

I have this :

```
function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight-30;
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
    createjs.Ticker.framerate = 65;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "Pics/tipeee-logo-pointcom-RVB.png";
    image.onload = function(){ 
    var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    stage.addChild(bitmap)
    ;};
}

function tick(event){
    init();
    stage.update();
}
```

There's more code within the functions, but nothing to do with the image, and no image is dispayed. 
Can you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hello,

Does your image.src need a "/" before the path like "/Pics/tipee..." ??

Was having some issues with the src sometimes.

Comment: Why is your `init()` function in the `tick` method? That will make it fire every tick (at ~65fps). What calls init initially? Perhaps the `init()` should be below everything so it is called once. Hopefully that solves your issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't see your answers !
The / before the path doesn't work.

If I don't call init() in my tick function, nothing happens, I don't have any animations at all. At first it's called in the body tag with an onload.

Any other ideas ? Thanks for your help !